# How can I extract C/C++ functions, methods, and variables in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

There are no "Extract Method / Member Function" or "Extract Variable" actions when I click the right button to open the context menu in a C++ file editor.

[This is a photo I saw from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63446179/11107541) where these actions exist in the context menu for Python files.

But when I work with C/C++ files, I don't have such actions in my context menu. [Here's a screenshot of my context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2xc6.png).

[Here's my VS Code version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpX8e.png).

Comment: Could that be some extension which is missing for you? Another possibility is different versions of either VS Code itself or of the extension.

Comment: From the documentation, VS code supports refactoring natively only for Javascript and Typescript. You need an extension to support that for other languages. The photo you found is about python but you've tagged this as C++, so maybe install the Microsoft C++ Extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing with the Python extension is there because the Python extension contributes the feature ([docs](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/FAQ.md#what-features-are-in-pylance-but-not-in-pyright-what-is-the-difference-exactly)).

At the time of this writing, the vscode-cpptools extension doesn't *yet* support this, but it's in their triage queue: [Extract function / member function
#1162](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1162) and [Add support for the Extract Variable refactoring #10930](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10930). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Consider also upvoting the backing Visual Studio feature-requests: [C++: Add Extract Variable refactoring](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C:-Add-Extract-Variable-refactoring/10357919).

The issue ticket was previously waiting on another change it has a dependency on: [Add the ability to generate definitions from declarations and vice versa
#664](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/664), which [was closed as completed on 2022-12-07](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/664#event-7980898849).

#### [v1.18.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/v1.18.0) update

The extension now has preliminary / experimental support for extracting functions. There are [a lot of known bugs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Feature%3A+Extract+to+function%22) that are being worked on, and bugs still being discovered. Quoting Sean McManus in [their announcement](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1162#issuecomment-1761906004), to opt into the feature,

> 0. Set `C_Cpp.experimentalFeatures` to `enabled`.
> 1. Select the code you want to extract to a function.
> 2. Select the "Extract to function" code action.
> 3. If the "Expand selection" code action appears, use that first.
> 4. If no code action appears, you can use Ctrl+Shift+R Ctrl+E to get an error message that may explain the reason for it not being available.
> 5. A rename prompt will appear, so use that, but we're planning to change it to prompt for the name before generating the code instead of doing a rename ([Prompt for the new function name before generating code for "Extract to function" #11531](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11531)).
> 6. Afterwards the code will be formatted, but there are various issues that could cause formatting to not work, so we're looking into fixing those issues and/or formatting the code before it's generated ([Format for Create declaration/definition (and "Extract to function") should be done within operation #10236](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10236)).

#### 1.18.4 update

This is [now released](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1162#issuecomment-1815490024) and you don't need to set `C_Cpp.experimentalFeatures` to get it. As before, there are still [known issues being tracked](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Feature%3A+Extract+to+function%22).

---

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues extract method`".